# Why does this function run orders of magnitude faster the second time round?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq

I inserted a new column `HashHash` into a table.  I then needed to write a small function that sets the value of `HashHash` to `Sha1(Row.Hash)`:

```
public static void UpdateAllHashHashes()
{
    using (var db = new MainContext())
    {
        var q = db.v2Hashes;
        foreach (var rec in q)
        {
            rec.HashHash = GetSha1(rec.Hash);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The table has thousands of records.  The first time I ran it, it took a good few minutes.  It threw an error near the end which caused it to not finish and leave ~20 records unprocessed, which I was semi-expecting so I ran the function again to get the last records which worked fine.

- First time around, it took ~2 minutes
- Second time around it took ~2 seconds

Was the reason the second pass so quick because `db.SubmitChanges` doesn't actually execute the SQL because the value hasn't changed?  I would of still expected it to run an `UPDATE` SQL query.

Or, is this a database engine optimisation somewhere?

Comment: If the value hasn't changed, I strongly suspect that's the reason why it's so much faster the second time. If you try and set a record to the same value it already has, it won't get marked dirty and therefore won't be updated when you `SubmitChanges`. As an aside, couldn't you move the `SubmitChanges` outside the loop?

Comment: @MattBurland I dont think he could unless he saves the rec changes to a location and ran the submit changes there. I think running submitchanges outside of the loop would just look at var 1 = db.v2hashes and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 5):

Submit changes only does changes that are actual changes. Updating the value of 12 to the new value of 12 is not a change.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

so yes your suspicions are right.